# Reusing structs from C in C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, struct, marshalling

Is it possible to import in C# structs definitions from C dlls?

In all the examples I saw were to redefine the structs in C#. What if the struct changes? I need to alter in two locations in my project...

```
struct MyCStruct
{
    unsigned long A;
    unsigned long B;
    unsigned long C;
};
```

and in C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct MyCStructAgain
    {
        public uint A;
        public uint B;
        public uint C;
    }
```

If It's not possible to reuse the definitions, why is that?

Thanks

Comment: _"If It's not possible to reuse the definitions, why is that?"_ - because it's a different language? :-)

Comment: Because C and C# are two different languages!

Comment: Yeah, but .NET makes all languages work together seamlessly...

Comment: Short answer, no. The only thing that can be seen in an unmanaged .dll are the exported function definitions.

Comment: .Net makes all languages work together seamlessly only if language is .net compliant. Whereas C is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compile your structs as C++/CLI where the compiler generates the managed counterparts for you and you can reference them then. You would need an ifdef to prepend value to make it a .NET struct.

```
#ifdef CLIEXPORT
#define value
#endif

CLIEXPORT struct MyCStruct
{
    unsigned long A;
    unsigned long B;
    unsigned long C;
};
```